# Is there a nice formula for...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a convenient expression for something of the form

$$(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n)^n, \: n \in \mathbb{Z}^+?$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: If there is no relationship between $x_i$, there is no convenient formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k)^n$ expands into the sum of all terms of the form $$\binom{n}{c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k}a_1^{c_1}a_2^{c_2}\cdots a_k^{c_k}$$  where $c_i\in\Bbb N$ for each $i$, $c_1+c_2+\dots+c_k = n$ and $\binom{n}{c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k}=\frac{n!}{c_1!c_2!\cdots c_k!}$

This is the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)